How to stop survey email being sent out to customer went case is closed?
I am doing some Service cloud implementation. Would like to know how to disable the survey email sent out to customers when a case is closed.
The Survey email looks like the one in the image below.


Have you checked the documentation?

Thank for this @David Cheng. looks like i need better googling skills.

Option 1
If your org has Set Up > Support Settings > Customer Feedback Survey checked true, then uncheck it so no Survey automatically goes out on Case close
Option 2
If your org has Set Up > Support Settings > Customer Feedback Survey checked true, but you conditionally want surveys to go out for some closed cases ...

Uncheck the box
implement a Flow that considers the Case in question to see if eligible to send a survey and then use the Flow core action Send Survey

Option 3
If your org has Set Up > Support Settings > Customer Feedback Survey unchecked, then you must have some sort of automation where surveys are sent out - most likely a Flow though conceivably Apex or a third party package

Thank you, it worked.

@GurtejSingh -- glad to have helped.  As a service to the Community it is best practice to mark answers that solved your issue as accepted (use the check mark). This way , when others search for similar issues, they can see that the question was answered to the questioner's satisfaction
